# Define different routes inside routing.module

Tags: angular, angular-router

I want to define different routes according to a flag. This is part of

***app-routing.module.ts***

```
 import { Token } from "...";  //  InjectionToken

 let routes: Routes;
 @NgModule({
   imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
   exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
  constructor(@Inject(Token) private token) {
    if (this.token) {
      routes = [...]
    }
    else {
       routes =[...]
    }
  }
```

Unfortunately, the above does not work. Any idea how to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to set the router config as below:

```
import { Token } from "...";  //  InjectionToken

 let routes: Routes;
 @NgModule({
   imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
   exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
  constructor(@Inject(Token) private token,
   router: Router) {
    let config = router.config;
    if (this.token) {
      routes = [...]
    }
    else {
       routes =[...]
    }
    config = routes;
    router.resetConfig(config);
  }
}
```

A working example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-emnqvb

Comment: Strange, works for me. Only extra code I have is injecting `routerModule: RouterModule` into constructor edited the same. Make sure `routes` are setup properly.

Comment: Something is missing. What about `routerModule`? Where are you using it? How do we inform `RouterModule` that we want to change its `routes`?

Comment: @Unknowndeveloper Added a working example url to my answer. Note: the dynamically added routes need to be added in `entryComponents` in `app.module.ts`